# Receive onclick value from Android Library via Page Fragment

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-library

Currently I have Project A (as Android Library) and Project B.

In Project B I am using page fragment for the design. At page fragment 1, the fragment is actually called from Project A (the library).

How do i receive the onclick value on Project A to Project B.

**// Declare the fragment page on Project B**

`CustFragment fragment1 = new CustFragment ();`

**// onclick listener on Project A**

```
mContactList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);

            long rawId = cursor.getLong(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID));
```

`// how do i pass the value to B?`

```
        }
```

EDITED: I edited this post with more code from my side

// Declare the fragment on Project B

```
public class MainPagerFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

ListFragment list;
SearchFragment search;  
public MainPagerFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    super(fragmentManager);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 2;
}

public String getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0: return AppSingleton.getCurrentActivity().getString(R.string.pager_appointments_tab);
        case 1: return  AppSingleton.getCurrentActivity().getString(R.string.explist_filter_text);
    }
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {             
        case 0:
            if (customerList == null)
                list = new ListFragment();
            return customerList;
        case 1:
            if (contactSearch == null)
                search = new SearchFragment();
            return contactSearch;
    }

    return null;
}
```

}

// onclick listener on Project A (library project)

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    log.info("ContactsFragment onCreateView");
    mContactFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts,
            container, false);

    mContactList = (ListView) mContactFragmentView
            .findViewById(R.id.contacts_list);

    mContactList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);

            long rawId = cursor.getLong(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID));

            // what have to done here to pass back to B dynamically

        }

    });
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    return mContactFragmentView;
}
```

- java.lang.NullPointerException at
  com.contact.library.ContactsFragment$2.onItemClick(ContactsFragment.java:143)
  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:308)
  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1509)
  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3467)
  at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4830) at
  android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) at
  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) at
  android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) at
  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602) at
  java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) at
  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) at
  dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

You want to set up a callback triggered on Fragment A. Similar to this:

create an interface in your library:

```
public interface MyInterface {
  public void onRawIdAcquired(long rawId);
}
```

Create an instance of it somewhere in your FragmentA (and make a setter that can set its value):

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
...
MyInterface i;
...
public void setListener(MyInterface i) {
  this.i = i;
}
```

then call it when rowId gets the value:

```
long rawId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID));
i.onRawIdAcquired(rawId);
```

Now in your PageFragment in your non-library activty, implement MyInterface and override onRawIdAcquired:

```
public PageFragment extends Fragment implements MyInterface {
@Override
public void onRawIdAcquired(long rawId) {
  **// you can now use the value of rawId here.**
}
```

Finally, somewhere when instantiating your FragmentA, pass PageFragment in setListener:

```
FragmentA f = ...;
PageFragment myPageFragment = ...;
f.setListener(myPageFragment);
```

Comment: Project A is a library, i want to make it dynamic so any other project could when click on the Item could return back to Project B without big modification of code

Comment: maybe i didn't understand your question. do you want to get hold of the OnClickListener object, or just the value of rawID?

Comment: my idea is to have the value of rawID from Project A pass to Project B

Comment: Ah. then you need some kind of callback. I'll update my answer.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but when i implements the MyInterface in non-library project it gives me error

Comment: the IDE will ask me to create MyInterface in the non-library project

Comment: other than that, when i click on the list item it will generate NullPointerException error when calling the interface method

Comment: that's weird. can you post the exact error, maybe a screenshot?

Comment: hi, i had updated my question with more code and the error. Could one of the reason is i somehow miss out the last part of your code, cause i not sure which part should implement it

Comment: right now i can implements MyInterface on the PagerAdapater but when execute i.onRawIdAcquired(rawId); it give error

Answer (score 0):

In your library project, create global variable that variable call from your fragment. If you want to easy way, you should try this way. Just my idea. Hope for help. [Android main project with library project - how to pass setting between projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269157/android-main-project-with-library-project-how-to-pass-setting-between-projects)

Comment: hi, i am trying to use Interface to solve the problem but it give me nullpointerexception when i call the interface method

Comment: This is global variable using sample. http://stackoverflow.com/a/708317/3247356  OR http://stackoverflow.com/a/1945297/3247356